# Is it better to store recursive data in one OR two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

Goal: For a simple toDo app, tasks and possible subtasks needs to be stored (Model 1).

Is it "better" to have one table that is using recursive relations OR to use two tables? Advantages/disadvantages in your opinion? Positive/negative effects on performance, useability, etc. Is it even correct to use the recursive one this way ?

Model 1: **Tasks** and **subtasks** in two tables. *More subtask levels are not necessary.*

[image]

Model 2: **Tasks** and **subtasks** in one table. Btw, is it correct, that with this design to have unlimited **subtask**-levels (beside technical bounderies) ? task-subtask-subtask-...

[image]

Comment: Don't make it harder than nessesary! A task is a task, there are (as I can see) no difference, only the possible parent. So stick to model 2.

Comment: You have to modify model 2.  You don't want a subtask id, you want a parent task id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you form your question this way and what confuses you.
A classical example of a database is one that stores employees. In the employees table you also store managers as managers are also employees. So what you describe as model 2 is not something "weird".
Self join is a common query.
Try to define the tables in a way that will make your queries as simple as possible and your model easy to understand and extend.
In your case you should define a second table only if each subtask has extra information that other tasks do not.
In your model 1 as you describe it you just duplicate the columns of your main table. This is not a good design IMO.
As far as I can see model 2 fits what you are trying to do.

Comment: well, my first design was quite different (more attributes). Then I cleaned up, other ideas and voila, the subtask was like the task. Since I never did a self join before, I was a little concerned, since it looked so elegant, that I oversee something. Anyway, your argument about the different information between a task and subtask helps me to see it clear. Still the features of the app is open and what kind of information needs to be stored, in a task or in the subtasks. Also the depth of subtasks is unclear yet. The goal is to keep it as simple as possible. Thank you!